# Installation of ffmpeg and others on UWAMP

Tags: ffmpeg, uwamp, clipbucket

i try to install clip bucket for making a youtube clone site  but the  script ask to install ffmpeg and others compression tools on the server and i dont know how to do it .
Lots of online host dont allow those libs for free.
I use UWAMP but dont know how to install ffmpeg on UWAMP ...
Anyone know ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using Windows, if yes then you can install FFMPEG using following link.

https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Installing-FFmpeg

Yes, you need SSH access for install FFMPEG and other tool on server. Free web-hosting does allow you to install FFMPEG and other Libraries. You need Atleast VPS for this.